# XNA linking two games

Tags: xna

does anyone know how to link one game after another? e.g. after completing all the levels of the default game, the next game will load up (kinda like a bonus game for completing the first game).

At the moment i'm using the platformer starter kit distributed from Microsoft and would like that game to link to my own game after all the levels in the platformer have been completed.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you add your game into the Platformer Starter kit and then call it add the end of the last level?

Answer (score 0):

The most integrated way would be to use have one solution (but separate projects, if need be) that contains all of your code. This way you can easily call any code you need between the games.

If you wanted this to all happen in the same window, you could swap out the view that controls the platformer game in place of the view that controls your game logic. [Here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) is a very good example for managing game state; you could use this to swap the views in and out.